# Closeness and “alongside”

Tags: word-usage

When describing the relative position of two line segments, one might use the word *alongside* to communicate that the line segments are close together and run parallel to one another.

I'm trying to determine how close two line segments need to be in order for *alongside* to be a reasonable description of their relative position.

For example, if a 13 foot section of gas line runs parallel to a 13 foot long wall of a house, how close would the two need to be in order for the statement “the gas line runs alongside the wall” to be accurate?

If the distance between the two segments is significantly less than the distance between the beginning and end of each segment, could they be considered to be close enough that they run *alongside* one another? For example, if the gas line in the above example lies 7 feet from the wall, would it be reasonable to say that it runs *alongside* the wall?

Comment: If something runs alongside something, one presumes it follows the other line. However, that does not imply the ***actual distance between the two lines***. You have to say: it runs alongside the wall with an offset of two feet [from the wall]. For example. If the distances vary because the running line's offset to the wall varies, you have to say that in your text.

Comment: @Lambie, fair enough, but I'm wondering at what point *alongside* is no longer correct. For example, if I said “it runs alongside the wall with an offset of fifty feet” and the wall is only 13 feet long, I assume this would not be correct use of alongside, since it's not “close enough” at that point.

Comment: There is no hard rule for what will qualify as "alongside", but I would disagree with @Lambie that there is *no* implication of distance. "Alongside" implies relative closeness. I would generally agree with the idea that "alongside" is most fitting when the distance between the segments is less than the length of each segment. However, that is more a matter of preference and not an actual rule.

Comment: I'd say over two feet is pushing it in your example.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth can you explain how you came to that conclusion? How do you determine what distance is close enough for alongside to be appropriate?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I agree to an extent. If somebody told me *the pipe runs alongside the north wall of the house*, I'd assume something around two feet or less. But, if somebody told me *the pipe runs alongside the north wall of the house, about 7 feet out*, that wouldn't seem wrong to me at all.

Comment: I doubt if we'd say that two pipelines ran alongside each other if they were 10 miles apart. However, 100 yards? Maybe, if their length was long enough. It all depends on your point of view -- 100 yards apart may be considered to be practically on top of one another by oil and gas engineers.

Comment: Alongside means next to, or as close as can be. If a road runs alongside a railroad track, the right of way for the road and railroad are touching. If a pipe runs alongside a wall, the trench was dug right next to the wall, and the pipe dropped in, so not more than a foot. Alongside implies there is nothing betwixt.

Comment: So there's your answer: it depends on who you are taking to. I haven't found any definition or usage guide that gives a rule, and even if there were one I wouldn't expect it to hold true for everybody. Some people think "alongside" means "close as can be", but others (like me) think that it isn't nearly so strict. The take-home is this - if you use the word, "alongside", then you should also specify the offset, unless you want to be vague.

Comment: I wouldn't use an airport where the active runways were "alongside" each other.

Comment: @Phil Sweet Your answer contradicts that of [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alongside) 
(Along, near, at, or to the side) in **insisting** that there is 'nothing betwixt'. And they do their research.

Comment: I said two feet, you could say two inches or one foot. My POINT was that the word alongside does not designate the distance offset from the line of reference. Yes, it has to be reasonably near. But it also depends: A line could run alongside a large pipeline at 25 feet out and alongside would still work.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I will gladly desist in my insistence, if that's what it was. But I don't see any contradiction with AHD. If a dog is "along, near, at, or to the side" of you, it is alongside you, provided there isn't a wall or something between you. I wouldn't say the neighbor's dog came up alongside me if there was a fence between us. I'd say he came up alongside the fence.

Comment: @PhilSweet, in your example the fence seems relevant, but I don't believe that's always the case. Imagine a row of ten houses all built alongside one another (with no fences). Now suppose someone builds a fence between two of the houses. According to your definition, those two houses are no longer alongside each other, while the others still are. None of the houses have moved. If *alongside* describes the relationship between two objects, it seems odd that the relationship would change when a third object is introduced.

Comment: @Phil Sweet AHD allows a pipe 1 foot away (which almost everyone would say fulfils the 'near' requirement) whereas you said it had to be 'as near as possible' (possibly no more than 3").

Comment: The word _alongside(s)_ does not apply to line segments. It refers to boats and implies that there are two sides (not lengths, physical sides) of two boats that lie more or less parallel (but  both boats are floating and therefore in motion, so not actually parallel). If one vessel is alongside another, things and people can move directly from one to another, under normal circumstances.