# How to say things are positioned or placed next to each other without any space in between?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Looking for a word to express objects being aligned next to each other without any space in between.

Comment: Look up [adjacent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjacent) and its synonyms.

Comment: @Glorfindel - *adjacency* doesn’t require ***touching*** or ***abuttment***

Comment: In some cases (mathematics) it does. That's why the OP needs to provide more detail as well.

Comment: Continguous is another possibility.  But, @Mayank, please provide context and explain the research you've done thus far.  And look up the definition of _write_.

Comment: Contiguous, that should have been.

Comment: You mean like "crammed in together"?

Comment: @Jim abutting or touching maybe contacting but less aligned than something adjacent which is more typically immediately alongside. A lot might abut another property at the rear corner but more likely be described as "adjacent" to it's neighbor to the side....I think much of the correct word choice would depend on the traditional use within different contexts

Comment: With trepidation, I suggest *alongside* would normally be adequate. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355866/closeness-and-alongside

Comment: cheek by jowl? (a joke!).

Answer (score 9):

**flush**

adjective

1.
even or level, as with a surface; forming the same plane:
*The bottom of the window is* ***flush with*** *the floor*.

2.
having direct contact; being right next to; immediately adjacent; contiguous:
*The table was* ***flush against*** *the wall.*

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flush?s=t

Answer (score 3):

**abut/abutting**

1.) To touch or lean upon.

2.) To be adjacent to, border at.

Comment: Please consider adding the source of your definition.

Answer (score 3):

(I noticed this was in the comments by @Glorfindel after I posted - the full definition including it's mathematical meaning may be worth considering )

I think "adjacent" is a bit more common and word more appropiate with things such as the examples below...however the other answers emphasize the "no space between" more firmly:

***[adjacent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adjacent)***
ADJECTIVE

> 1 Next to or adjoining something else.
>
> ‘adjacent rooms’
>
> ‘the area adjacent to the station’
>
> 2 Geometry
>
> (of a pair of angles) formed on the same side of a straight line when intersected by another line.